# Unable to access MongoDB collection from shell when the name contains '-'

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-shell

I have a collection named GoldenGlobes-emotion in my MongoDB 2.6.9
I found I can not access this collection from the MongoDB shell
When ever I try to access the collection, for example

```
db.GoldenGlobes-emotion.findOne()
```

I always got this:

```
ReferenceError: emotion is not defined
```

But it works well when I access the collection form Python with PyMongo.
Is this a shell bug? 
Or '-'  is a reserved character？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `db["GoldenGlobes-emotion"].findOne()`.

The MongoDB shell is a Javascript interpreter. Javascript does not allow hyphens in variable names, because it interprets them as the minus-operator. However, you can also access object-fields with string literals by using the array-syntax. In that case, this restriction does not apply.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Now I can rename the collection from shell :D